# Generalized Binary Representation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, representation-theory

Let $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < \dots$ be a sequence of positive integers with $a_1 = 1$ and $a_n < a_{n+1} ≤ 2a_n$. Show that any positive integer $m$ can be written as a sum of distinct elements of this sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> **Lemma.** Given $m$ positive integer, there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{m}{2}<a_n\le m$.

If $m = 1$, just take $n = 1$. Otherwise, the set $\{k\in\Bbb N: a_k\le \frac{m}{2}\}$ is not empty (and obviously limited), so let $n$ be its maximum value. Then $\dfrac{m}{2}<a_{n+1}$ (otherwise $n+1$ would be on the set and $n$ wouldn't be its maximum) and $a_{n+1}\le 2a_n\le 2\dfrac{m}{2} = m$.
$~\square$

Using this lemma, we can prove the statement by strong induction. The base case is trivial, so assume that every positive integer less than $m$ can be written as a sum of distinct elements of the sequence. In particular, there are $i_1, i_2, \dots, i_k$, all distinct, such that $m-a_n = a_{i_1}+a_{i_2}+\dots a_{i_k}$. If $n$ is given by the previous lemma, than of course $n\neq i_j$, since $a_n > \dfrac{m}{2}$ and $a_{i_j} \le m-a_n<\dfrac{m}{2}$. Therefore, $a_n+a_{i_1}+a_{i_2}+\dots a_{i_k}$ is a way to write $m$ as a sum of distinct elements of the sequence, and the induction is complete.

Comment: Thank you for your help! and by the way, since I gaped 1 and half year. Those knowledge is far from me, like what lemma or knowledge should I know in this question?

Comment: In fact, you are dealing with **mixed radix representations** which belong to the category of **positional numeration systems**. Their principle is exposed in the excellent answer [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/57149/98622) and with more detail in D. Knuth "The Art of Computer Programming" Vol. 2 pages 208-209 in its 3rd edition.